# segmentation fault in ofstream close c++

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, ofstream

well i'm hardly trying to figure out why a segmentation fault occurs in the following code in one of my classes, the function is called once,

```
void fileTransfer::createFile(){
   std::ofstream fout;
   fout.open("th.txt", std::ios::binary | std::ios::out);
   char *toSend = new char();
   for (int i=0;i<totalSize_;i++) {
      toSend[i]=totalData_.front();
      totalData_.pop_front();
   }
   std::cout<<"stage 1"<< std::endl;
   fout.write(toSend, totalSize_);
   fout.flush();
   std::cout<<"stage 2"<< std::endl;
   fout.close();
   std::cout<<"stage 3"<< std::endl;
}
```

and i'm getting:

```
stage 1
stage 2
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

any ideas why is this happening?

Comment: `char *toSend = new char();` -- Why not simply `char toSend;`?  Why introduce `new` and a memory leak for no reason?

Comment: Your toSend can only hold one char. Instead use new char[totalSize_]:

Comment: What is `totalData_`?

Comment: How about `toSend.push_back(totalData_.front())`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This:

```
  char *toSend = new char();
```

creates a pointer that points to a single dynamically allocated character, which you then treat as if it were an array of multiple characters. You could use:

```
  char *toSend = new char[totalSize];
```

or similar, but really you want to use  a `std::vector <char>` or a `std::string`.

Comment: im in love with you right now, such a foolish mistake made by me, thanks!